# Why are there two values for single corner radius in GradientDrawable.setCornerRadii for?

Tags: android, cornerradius, gradientdrawable

From android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#setCornerRadii(float[])), the **GradientDrawable.setCornerRadii (float[] radii)**
 method:

> Specifies radii for each of the 4 corners. For each corner, the array
>   contains 2 values

Why are there 2 values for each corner? What is the meaning of two values for a single corner?

Answer (score 0):

One value is for the X_radius the other for the Y_Radius.  If they are equal you'll get an even radius.  If they are different it will be distorted in one dimension or the other (look more like a logarithmic curve for example).